# Dimension of the intersection of an irreducible projective set with a general $k$-plane that meets it.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\Lambda\subseteq \mathbb{P}^{n}$ be a linear subspace of dimension $k$, and let $X\subseteq\mathbb{P}^{n}$ be an irreducible projective set of dimension $r$. Let us suppose that $X\cap \Lambda\neq \emptyset$. Which is the dimension of $X\cap \Lambda$ for a general $\Lambda$ satisfying this condition?

Comment: The required dimension is $\max (r+k-n,0)$.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Is it true that a general line $\Lambda$ that intersects $X$ satisfies #$\Lambda\cap X=\deg X$?

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

$r-(n-k)$ because $\Lambda$ is defined by (the vanishing of) $n-k$ hyperplanes, and intersecting $X$ with a general hyperplane drops the dimension by $1$.

Comment: what if $r+k< n$ ? oh no !